# How to make MySQL MAX() consider NULL the smallest possible value?

Tags: sql, mysql, null, max

I have a query that looks a bit like this:

```
SELECT weekEnd, MAX(timeMonday)
FROM timesheet
GROUP BY weekEnd
```

The valid values for timeMonday are: null, -1, 0, 1-24. At the moment, MAX() places the preference of those values in the order null, -1, 0, 1-24, however what I actually want is -1, null, 0, 1-24, so that null is considered higher than -1. I know MAX cant do this, so what's the easiest way to achieve it?

Comment: What is `1-24`? Max date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763806/mysql-ignores-null-value-when-using-max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SELECT weekEnd, MAX(coalesce(timeMonday,-.5))
>   FROM timesheet
>   GROUP BY weekEnd

Then convert -.5 back to null

Comment: PROTIP for future googlers: use the `AS` keyword to name your column for easier access from programs. `SELECT weekEnd, MAX(coalesce(timeMonday,-.5)) AS max_monday FROM timesheet GROUP BY weekEnd`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT weekEnd, CASE WHEN maxTimeMonday = -0.5 THEN NULL ELSE maxTimeMonday END maxTimeMonday 
FROM (
   SELECT weekEnd, MAX(CASE WHEN timeMonday IS NULL THEN -0.5 ELSE timeMonday END) maxTimeMonday 
     FROM timesheet
    GROUP BY weekEnd) T
```

replacing NULL by -0.5 when calculating MAX then reverting it to NULL.

(MS SQL Server syntax)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT weekEnd, MAX(COALESCE(timeMonday, '-0.1'))
FROM timesheet
GROUP BY weekEnd
```

Edit: haven't tested this

```
SELECT weekEnd, REPLACE(MAX(COALESCE(timeMonday, '-0.1')), '-0.1', 'null')
FROM timesheet
GROUP BY weekEnd
```

Comment: You closed bracket to early

SELECT weekEnd, MAX(COALESCE(timeMonday, '-0.1'))