# Selecting single max values

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

Say I need to pull data from several tables like so:

```
item 1 - from table 1
item 2 - from table 1
item 3 - from table 1 - but select only max value of item 3 from table 1
item 4 - from table 2 - but select only max value of item 4 from table 2
```

My query is pretty simple:

```
select
    a.item 1,
    a.item 2,
    b.item 3,
    c.item 4
from table 1 a
left join (select b.key_item, max(item 3) from table 1, group by key_item) b on a.key_item = b.key_item
left join (select c.key_item, max(item 4) from table 2, group by key_item) c on c.key_item = a.key_item
```

I am not sure if my methodology of pulling just a single max item from a table is the most efficient. Assume both tables are over a million rows.  my actual sql run forever using this sql setup.

EDIT:  I changed the group by clause to reflect comments made. I hope it makes a bit of sense now?

Comment: You should edit your question with the actual SQL you are running.  Your query as written makes no sense.  You are aggregating by one set of columns and then choosing other columns.

Comment: my actual sql is exactly like this with the names of the tables and columns changed . Why does the query not make sense? I am only looking to get the max value of a particular item and not the whole row so why aggregate over the whole row?

Comment: can you show us the sample data and desire output?

Comment: @user2022284 Using `GROUP BY` is like saying "return just one row for each unique value in this column." So, `(select b.key_item, max(item 3) from table 1 b, group by item 3)` will look at all the rows in `table 1`, and return one row for each distinct value of `item 3`. The values SELECTed will be *any* random key_item that has the `item 3` value for that row, and then the `MAX` of all the `item 3` values for that `item 3` value. Except, the max of one value is just that value. See why it doesn't make sense? Whereas, if you `GROUP BY key_item`, you'll get the max `item 3` for each `key_item`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @William. I see what you mean. Will modify  my code to see what happens. Will also try Mohamed's version below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to add an index on `table1` and `table2`, as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD INDEX `GoodIndexName1` (`key_item`,`item3`)

ALTER TABLE table2
ADD INDEX `GoodIndexName2` (`key_item`,`item4`)
```

This will allow you to use [queries as described in the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) for finding the rows holding the group-wise maximum, which appears to be what you are looking for.

Your original (edited) query should work:

```
select
    a.item1,
    a.item2,
    b.item3,
    c.item4
from table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    b.key_item, 
    MAX(item3) AS item3
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY key_item
) b 
ON a.key_item = b.key_item
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    c.key_item, 
    MAX(item4) 
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY key_item
) c 
ON c.key_item = a.key_item
```

and if that performs slowly after adding the indexes, try the following too:

```
SELECT
    a.item1,
    a.item2,
    b.item3,
    c.item4
FROM table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 b
ON b.key_item = a.key_item
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 larger_b
ON larger_b.key_item = b.key_item
AND larger_b.item3 > b.item_3
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 c
ON c.key_item = a.key_item
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 larger_c
ON larger_c.key_item = c.key_item
AND larger_c.item4 > c.item4
WHERE larger_b.key_item IS NULL
AND larger_c.key_item IS NULL
```

(I have modified the table and column names only slightly, so that they conform to correct MySQL syntax. )

I work with queries that use the above structure all the time, and they perform very efficiently with indexes like the one I provided.

That said, usually I am using INNER JOINs on the `b` and `c` tables, but I don't see why your query should have any issues.

If you do experience performance problems still, report the data types of the `key_item` columns for each table, as if you try to join on different data types, you will generally get poor performance.

Comment: Wonderful, @Willem, will implement and report back tomorrow am. Thanks

Comment: The second solution worked. it was much faster than the first.  thank you. I'd like to understand the methodology a bit - a learning experience.  I get the part about joining the table to itself and comparing the field whose max value we are looking for. I don't get the part where a null value is specified for the larger _c.key_item. What exactly does that do?

Comment: The join to the `larger_c` table is meant to join all records that are larger than the records in the `c` table. If we then specify that the `larger_c` record should not exist, by requiring a non-null column to be null (the `key_item` column in this case), then we only obtain the record(s) from the `c` table for which there are no larger values of `item4`. That is, the record(s) with the maximum value for `item4`.

Comment: What happens if there are two items in c with a max value? what about nulls?

Comment: If there are 2 items with the same max value, then you will get back multiple rows in your final query, with the same results. You can remove those with a `DISTINCT`. If you have only nulls, I suspect you'll just get a null for the `item3` value.

Comment: back again - one last clarification about nulls. What if there are values including nulls. Will this pick the max date over the null ?

Comment: I believe it should, yes, based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763806/mysql-ignores-null-value-when-using-max

Comment: I have a new wrinkle to this. What if I need the max value in a third table ( table 3)  - but its not directly linked to table 1. Rather you can get to it from  table 1 -> table 2 -> table 3.  Table 3 is only linkable to table 2.  I used the above method by adding one more layer of left outer join from table 2 to table 3 but got multiple rows returned, instead of just one row with the max value.

Comment: Start a new question, and post the link to it here. I'll look at it if I have time, else someone else may be able to help you. Be sure to include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` definitions, and the full query you are trying to make, even if you do change the column names. That information is very important to have in order to be able to answer your question well.