# MySQL query using group by with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, group-by, multiple-conditions

**EDIT:**
I have removed the confusing remark at the end and added an additional column pl_id which I thought irrelevant (due to my apparent lack of understanding the `group by` workings). When trying the suggestions posted, I ran into a problem where introducing the MAX/Group By would result in

```
  | name  | license_plate | pl_id | start_date |
  | aaron | AA-AA-22      |     3 | 2016-1-1   |
```

Where i expected:

```
  | name  | license_plate | pl_id | start_date |
  | aaron | AA-AA-22      |     4 | 2016-1-1   |
```

So somehow the max date for license plate AA-AA-22, which is 2016-1-1, appears in the record with pl_id = 3, why does the result return a record with the date from pl_id 4? 
**END EDIT**

I have a table with columns:

- name
- license_plate
- start_date

I need a query that returns exactly one record for each license plate with the maximum start_date or where start_date is empty. But empty start_date should take precedence above maximum start_date.

Each license plate is guaranteed to have at most one entry with start_date = null but can have multiple entries with valid 'start_date'-s.

So for example, when executed on the following table:

```
  | name  | license_plate | pl_id | start_date |
  | aaron | AA-AA-11      |     1 | 2015-1-1   |
  | aaron | AA-AA-11      |     2 | null       |
  | aaron | AA-AA-22      |     3 | 2015-1-1   |
  | aaron | AA-AA-22      |     4 | 2016-1-1   |
  | bill  | BB-BB-11      |     5 | 2015-1-1   |
  | bill  | BB-BB-11      |     6 | null       |
  | bill  | BB-BB-22      |     7 | 2015-1-1   |
  | clark | CC-CC-11      |     8 | 2015-1-1   |
  | clark | CC-CC-11      |     9 | 2016-1-1   |
  | dave  | DD-DD-11      |    10 | 2014-1-1   |
  | dave  | DD-DD-11      |    11 | 2015-1-1   |
  | dave  | DD-DD-11      |    12 | 2016-1-1   |
  | eddy  | EE-EE-11      |    13 | null       |
```

The query should return:

```
  | name  | license_plate | pl_id | start_date |
  | aaron | AA-AA-11      |     2 | null       |
  | aaron | AA-AA-22      |     4 | 2016-1-1   |
  | bill  | BB-BB-11      |     6 | null       |
  | bill  | BB-BB-22      |     7 | 2015-1-1   |
  | clark | CC-CC-11      |     9 | 2016-1-1   |
  | dave  | DD-DD-11      |    12 | 2016-1-1   |
  | eddy  | EE-EE-11      |    13 | null       |
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT name, license_plate, IF(max(IF(start_date IS NULL, '2099-01-01',  start_date)) = '2099-01-01', null, max(start_date)) 
FROM table
GROUP BY name, license_plate;
```

You can change '2099-01-01' to some bigger number if needed.

Tested on your dataset.

Answer (score 4):

I'm confused, from your example you seem to want to take `null` priority over any real dates - I just don't see how that relates to group by multiple conditions...
Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19763904/6318822) can help you?

```
SELECT
    `name`,
    license_plate,
    CASE
        WHEN MAX(start_date IS NULL) = 0 THEN MAX(start_date)
    END AS start_date
FROM
    plates
GROUP BY
    `name`,
    license_plate
```

Output:

```
+-------+---------------+------------+
| name  | license_plate | start_date |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| aaron | AA-AA-11      | NULL       |
| aaron | AA-AA-22      | 2016-01-01 |
| bill  | BB-BB-11      | NULL       |
| bill  | BB-BB-22      | 2015-01-01 |
| clark | CC-CC-11      | 2016-01-01 |
| dave  | DD-DD-11      | 2016-01-01 |
| eddy  | EE-EE-11      | NULL       |
+-------+---------------+------------+
7 rows in set
```

Comment: Also my answer will give the result, Your answer is better.

Comment: Thanks, indeed the post you are referring to seems to be exactly my question. I am now trying to get your solution to work. However, I am bumping into some very strange problems. The point is, that my original table is itself the result of multiple `joins` and as soon as I introduce the `group by`, a get a result where the values of multiple records seem intermixed. This has probably to do with my bad understanding of the inner workings of a `group by`. So I will first study that some more. I do think though with this answer I should be able to figure it out. Will share results.

Comment: btw, my multiple conditions tag refers to `start_date is null` and `MAX(start_date)`

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 queries, One fo `NULL` values and another for `MAX(start_date)`

```
SELECT name, license_plate, MAX(start_date) FROM test.tab
group by name, license_plate having count(start_date) = count(name)

union 
select name, license_plate, start_date From test.tab
Where start_date is null
```

in this condition `count(start_date) = count(name)` you will discover records which have `null` values because `null` values does not computed in `count` sentence.

And the another `select` will return records with `start_date = null`.

You can add `where` condition to the second query if your database has more than one record has `null` value for the same `license_plate`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Group By

```
SELECT  distinct * FROM [tablename] where start_date is null or start_date group by 
license_number order by name,start_date
```

the "start_date is null" is for you to display first if there is a null in the  start_date in the group of license_plate and the "or start_date" is for you to display the other dates that is not null.

it will produce the same result:

```
| name  | license_plate | start_date |
| aaron | AA-AA-11      | null       | 
| aaron | AA-AA-22      | 2016-1-1   |
| bill  | BB-BB-11      | null       |
| bill  | BB-BB-22      | 2015-1-1   |
| clark | CC-CC-11      | 2016-1-1   |
| dave  | DD-DD-11      | 2016-1-1   |
| eddy  | EE-EE-11      | null       |
```

Here is a capture of the result:

[image]
[image: Here is a capture of the result]